# IIS website keeps showing the default page

Tags: iis, web-server

I have configured a website within IIS 8 and I can't seem to get it to serve webpages from the physical path I specified.

My bindings are:

```
http:*:80:www.domain.com,http:*:80:domain.com
```

The website returns a 404 when accessed from domain.com, yet a 500 error when accessed from http://www.domain.com. I enabled the "failed request trace" log, but IIS isn't writing anything to the folder.

It seems that when domain.com is accessed, it simply defaults to the "default website", which is binded to *:80. However, http://www.domain.com returns a 500 error (and I don't see any logs with more info).

The folder that the documents should be served from is set to read/write/execute and  is located on the C:\ drive. I'm baffled, any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you enabled the module? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc754807(v=WS.10).aspx

Comment: I'm currently working on a script: [Test-WebSite.ps1](https://github.com/hahndorf/Test-WebSite) to help in such situations. You may want to try it.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to have www.domain.com and domain.com showing the same website?
If yes why do you have 2 bindings for that?

I would create 2 A-Records that will lead www.domain.com and domain.com to the same IP-address.

http "*" All Unassigned 80 YOUR_IP should to the rest for you then.

Check your ssl-settings. If you have the ssl-settings on "require SSL" you would get the 404 error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this still apply, even with multiple domains?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. How would you bind 2 domains on one port?